# html css structuring containers

Tags: html, css, containers

please see the test page on [www.derekho.co.uk](http://www.derekho.co.uk)

I'm wanting to 'empty' the container labelled with 'D' so that the body background tiles show through.

Container D needs a set width and needs to be centered. Any ideas?

Comment: I know I could do it with a table but that would be absolute last resort...

Comment: Thanks for everyone's time, this has been solved by nesting another div within the width:50% container and giving it margin-right:(half the ammount of pixels in the content container); Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

*As solved by asker:*

> http://www.derekho.co.uk/test.html

I suggest to use **floats instead of absolute positioning**. With absolute positioning you will have troubles when adding content on top and at bottom of the whole structure. For example, if you add a footer and side columns are bigger than the center one, footer will be positioned under these columns, they will cover it! Using floats, you can avoid this setting `clear: both;` for the footer element.

Float example:

> http://www.pmob.co.uk/temp/fixed-center-fluid-sides.htm

Comment: a new layout structure would be much appreciated. That's the design, can't really change it... trying to line up container D with the background texture is a bit clunky... no alternatives?

Comment: Ok, so, why have you come up with such layout? What do you want to realize? A simple 3 column layout, or more?

Comment: it's the background of the website. I think I've figured it out, thanks anyways

Comment: just for your information and anyone else interested, here's the solution. Thanks for your time. http://www.derekho.co.uk/test.html

Comment: Ok, so it's a basic 3 column layout with fixed size center column. Search the web for examples, there are better way to accomplish this. Your code is a bit messy...

Comment: is it? what ways are you referring to?

Comment: my code seems to be the very minimal and lean compared to some others I've found, if you know of a simpler solution do let me know.I guess I understand how something you percieved as impossible can feel 'messy' to you :)

Comment: @MrDerek I said that it was *not possible* to have colored boxes (B, C) under another box (D) and remove their background in correspondence of it (D). That is true. In fact, you had to resize those boxes (B, C) in a way so they don't go under the other (D). About the *messy code*, I was referring to absolute positioning of columns using *left/right* coordinates. You can use floats instead. **[This is an example showing it](http://www.pmob.co.uk/temp/fixed-center-fluid-sides.htm)**, but apart from using floats, it's messier than yours. You can work to take best from both solutions.